# Bearer token identity webapi - fine grained security

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, token, identity

we are developing AngularJS/SPA application of e.g. 500 forms, that connects to ASPNET WebAPI. Any form has "read", "write", "query" and "additional custom" access privileges. Access privileges can be grouped together in "roles". Each user can have defined one or more roles and/or specific privilege on a specific form.

I studied new Identity security framework with OpenId Connect/Oauth2 and token based authentication/authorization. Authentication works as user login to internal/external IdentityProvider(if successful, identity token is returned). Before accessing resource(web API), access token is needed. 
I was also palaying with identityserver V3, which looks nice product.
For authentication process(identity token), everything works fine.
For authorization process(access token), I can't find proper implementation details.

So questions here are:
1.) Security is defined using claims. If there are many claims per user(fine grained security, defined by user claims), does user need to ask IdentityProvider for access token every time before calling resource? 
What about overhead of user asking IdentityProvider every time resource is accessed?
Is allowed that user sends only identity token and resource then asks identity manager for access token(on user behalf)? 
Furthermore to optimize access framework, can IdentityManager directly access Provider database(instead of generating and verifying tokens). This technically means that IdentityProvider and ResourceProvider are tightly coupled.

2.) If privileges are not defined using claims. There is only identity token that is also access token at the same time. In application, there is internal ResourceManager, which stores access privileges(role based, fine grained) assigned to identity users. So ResourceManager act as filter in a way that identifies user from identity token, then checks database for access privileges and decides if resource can be used by an user. This means that ResourceProvider is a part of application and IdentityProvider is only used for authentication? Would this also fit to "modern" type of application security system?

3.) Hybrid option. IdentityProvider has identity and role claims. ResourceProvider maps roles and fine grained privileges to Identity roles/users. In this scenario I have no idea on how external providers, e.g. Google/FB can know what type of role our application requires?

4.) When using external identity provider, e.g. Google, which claims are generally usable for our application (except personal ones, e.g. Name, email, age, date of birth, etc.) from access privileges point of view? Bee Google admin (role) doesn't mean that it is admin of our app too?

Sorry for a long post :)
Rgds, 
Frenk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with IndentityServer, answer is simple. IdentityServer primary role is authentication/token generation. 
For authentication, application redirects to IdentityServer. IdentityServer returns token(identity, access) to client. That token is sent using HTML header(bearer token) to API. 
On API side, OWIN framework needs filters for token validation. Filters are implemented using "Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation". Filters are used by resource manager to check if particular API is allowed to be used by access token.

It is a question how to implement fine grained security. Problem is size of token(token is part of every call to WebAPI).
It is not right to mix resource managers with application. But for fine grained security, I believe this is the only option we have.

Also external provider can only return user claims that are are available there (google, facebook, etc.). Detailed description how external mechanism works is very precisely explained in a document on a page
[leastprivilege](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/26/dissecting-the-web-api-individual-accounts-templatepart-3-external-accounts/)

Comment: The only problem is not the size of token: it makes no sense to have maintain claims which are very, very specific to a particular application on an external server, because they're only useful for that application. Ant it's most probable that the authorization is configured in the application, or even depends on some business logic. The natural use of claims is for giving general information that can be used either in general cases (like an email account) or to access a resource from an external application (for example acccessing the contacts of gmail from an external app).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use claims for fine grained security. The main purpose of identity servers is authenticating, and generating the token so that the client can prove its identity to other services. Use it to athenticate, not to authorize.

In your Web API service, you can have your own authorization database with users, roles and privileges, so that this information is not represented by claims, but stored in this database. In this way all the knowledge about authorization can be handled by your application.

The last step is to map each user authenticated by an external authentication service to a user in your Web API authorization database.

Do you remember how you logged in to Stack Overflow? I do, and I have mapped two different Google accounts to my SO user account. I can login to SO using either of those Google accounts. So, SO doesn't take the responsibility to check who I am (authenticate), but once it receives the token form the external service it's sure of who I am and it can decide what I can do (authorization).

This is the most flexible way of working, without generating lots of claims. That's not the purpose of claims. I remember someone comparing a claim with a driving license: they are very similar because it's something created by a third party that gives information about a person. In real life rent-a-cars don't have to check if the person knows how to drive or not, because they can ask him for his driving license (this is like a claim) but, apart from having this information, they can decide to rent or not to rent the car depending on their own criteria (like an app authorization).

One advantage of mapping external authentication to application users is that you can easily change authentication providers, or use diffente ones. Perhaps you can also use some informations in the claims, like email accounts, but you don't depend on the claims for authroization.